# How to install specific version of Cap'n Proto (v0.8.0)?

Tags: serialization, rpc, capnproto

```
sudo apt install capnproto
```

This installs v0.7.0 in my ubuntu 20.04. However, i require v0.8.0 to be installed.

Also, i need  v0.6.1 to be installed additionally for backward compatibility.

Any solution for these two cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to install from source rather than use a distro package. Unfortunately, it sounds like the Ubuntu distro package hasn't been updated in a while.

Instructions for building and installing from source can be found here: https://capnproto.org/install.html

Old versions are available by changing the version number in the download URL to whichever version you need.

Note that all versions of Cap'n Proto are backwards-compatible, so there should be no need to install older versions, unless you need to run a specific complied binary that was linked against a specific old version.